# How to strip a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Atlassian doco here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHKB/Git+or+Hg+Repository+exceeds+number+of+allowed+Committers

states "Strip the repository that FishEye is indexing and push the rewritten-clone into it"

I have my converted repo but how do I strip the BitBucket repo that I'll push this converted repo in to?

Comment: This is a *bitbucket* question. The strip command has to be executed on your own clone, you can't remotely strip a repository, unless that repository host (bitbucket in this case) has set up a system to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

To strip changesets in a bitbucket repository you need to use the web interface on bitbucket.

First go to your repository on bitbucket, then click on the Settings menu item at the bottom left.

In the settings menu, under the General actions list, you should have a menu item called "Strip changesets", navigate to that.

Then, on the Strip changesets page, input the hash of the changeset you want to strip and click "Preview strip", and go from there.

[image: steps on bitbucket]

Answer (score 0):

The link for 'Strip' should probably point to https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension .

What it means is probably that you have to run `hg strip --keep .` on the repository configured into FishEye and then push your `rewritten-clone` repo into it.